# Selenium IDE - can I use ends-with on drop down ID element

Tags: selenium, xpath, ends-with

How can I use a Selenium IDE ends-with command on a drop down list ID which is dynamically generated but the last part remains the same?

I've tried

```
    select
    id=ends-with(@id, "_gridDropDownList")
    label=A

    select
    xpath=//name[ends-with(@id, "_gridDropDownList")]
    label=A
```

But I get an error that the element isn't found or invalid xpath.

Here is the HTML:

```
    <td class="select-field district2-field blogLocationAndTopicFields">
    <label></label>
    <select
    id="ctl00_m_g_a5a2d9db_4beb_87c2_ce5e339b9858_ctl00_gridDropDownList"
    class=""
    name="ctl00$m$g_a5a2d9db_4beb_87c2_ce5e339b9858$ctl00$gridDropDownList"
    style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></select>
```

Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 0):

I don't have selenium IDE to verify, but I strogly suspect this part is not valid :

```
id=ends-with(@id, "_gridDropDownList")
```

function [`ends-with()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-ends-with) returns boolean value, and the `id` which your code is comparing against most likely isn't a boolean. I guess you want to use [`substring-before()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-substring-before) instead :

```
id=substring-before(@id, "_gridDropDownList")
```

Answer (score 0):

If the all the attributes of html tag is dynamic.

Eg:

```
select id="0ef13ca7-905d-42c7-8e9a-0a94a1d71ceeF_EditIOT-widget-select" class="freedomSelect notDojoDndHandle" aria-required="false" dojoattachevent="onchange:onChange, onfocus:onFocus, onblur:onBlur" dojoattachpoint="comboNode, containerNode, focusNode"
```

And `select[ends-with(@id,'EditIOT-widget-select')]` is not working we can use "contains" function instant of sub string and ends- with function.

Try this:

```
select[contains(@id, 'EditIOT-widget-select')]
```